# How to print out an even number within 1 to10 digits in Perl using Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to repeatedly input a number which can be atleast 1 digit and maximum 10 digits. It should display that number on screen only if it is even number and between 1 and 10 digits, else it should exit the loop. I tried my code but not able to come up with the exact solution. I am trying to do using Regex. This is just for practice and has no other significance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/


while(<> =~ /^\d{1,10}$/)
{
        my $num = <STDIN>;
        if($num =~ /[123456789]+[02468]$/)
        { print STDOUT $num; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as follows, You are asking the stdin two times, first you should remove the stdin inside the loop.

```
while(my ($num) = <> =~ /^(\d{1,10})$/)  #Storing the digits in $num
{

    if($num =~ /^\d*[02468]$/) 
    { 
       print "Even $num\n"; 
    }
}
```

Actually you are trying to match two digits, `+` quantifiers matches atleast one character (this is your problem), and your are matching the even character `[02468]`. So I have added the `*` (match 0 or more times) instead of `+`.

Comment: Your or conditioning is unnecessary !!

Comment: Can you please also tell me where I was going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly urge not using regex to do arithmetic. Regular expressions are about pattern matching, not numbers. It'll only create you pain to try and do 'numeric' tests like 'is it even'.

But the root of your problem is you're reading `STDIN` twice. `<>` reads from it as does `<STDIN>`.

So how about instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
   my ( $num ) =  m/^(\d{1,10})$/ or last; #exit loop if it doesn't match. 
   print $num,"\n" unless $num % 2; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit your code like that:

```
if($num =~ /^\d*[02468]$/)
{ print STDOUT $num; }
```

[Run Here](https://ideone.com/VEeNGM)